# How to draw these polyhedrons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help drawing these two shapes in `LaTeX` witk `TikZ`. I got the octahedron one down. Now, I need help on the bipyramid one. Thank you! (and when I copy and paste from LaTeX to here, how do I put all the coding lines 4 spaces in? I had to do it individually for each line, which is a pain.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=5]
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (0.6,0.2);
    \coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (A4) at (0.4,-0.2);
    \coordinate (B1) at (0.5,0.5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (0.5,-0.5);

    \begin{scope}[thick,dashed,opacity=0.6]
        \draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw (B1) -- (A2) -- (B2);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    \draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    \draw[solid][line width=2pt] (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, TikZ is a good tool for it. Please share what you got so far and where you got stuck. That leaves less effort to the helpers, as they already hae a starting point.

Comment: For code typing here: insert the code, select all and press `Ctrl+k`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a fix for your code.

```
%
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=5]

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0.6,0.2);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (0.4,-0.2);
\coordinate (B1) at (0.5,0.5);
\coordinate (B2) at (0.5,-0.5);

\begin{scope}[thick,dashed,,opacity=0.6]
\draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
\draw (B1) -- (A2) -- (B2);
\end{scope}
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B1);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B1);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B2);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=5]

\coordinate (C1) at (0.2,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (0.8,-0.1);

\begin{scope}[thick,dashed,,opacity=0.6]
\draw (C1) -- (C2);

\end{scope}
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (C1) -- (A4) -- (B1);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (C1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (C2) -- (A4) -- (B1);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (C2) -- (A4) -- (B2);
\draw[solid][line width=2pt] (B1) -- (C1) -- (B2) -- (C2) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Sample output:

[image]

PS. To mass-edit code; mark the code and press this button:
[image]

Comment: How do I put these two shapes next to each other (like in the picture shown)? As of right now, one is above the other. Thank you!

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: A quick search gives you multiple instructions on how to do that.[How to draw two Tikz pictures that are parallel to each other?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24001/how-to-draw-two-tikz-pictures-that-are-parallel-to-each-other), [Two tikzpictures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213075/two-tikzpictures-side-by-side), [Is there a way to print two tikzpictures next to each other marked with a and b?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71386/is-there-a-way-to-print-two-tikzpictures-next-to-each-other-marked-with-a-and-b), etc.

Answer (score 6):

Here your MWE using the coordinate system `xyz` (and rounded line join and cap):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \path
  ( 1, 0, 0) coordinate (A1)
  ( 0, 0,-1) coordinate (A2)
  (-1, 0, 0) coordinate (A3)
  ( 0, 0, 1) coordinate (A4)
  ( 0, 1, 0) coordinate (B1)
  ( 0,-1, 0) coordinate (B2);

  \begin{scope}[very thin,draw=blue!50]
    \draw
    (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3)
    (B1) -- (A2) -- (B2);
  \end{scope}

  \draw[thick]
  (A1) -- (A4) -- (B1)
  (A1) -- (A4) -- (B2)
  (A3) -- (A4) -- (B1)
  (A3) -- (A4) -- (B2)
  (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s post to create your polyhdera. You can find his post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17209/161343).

```
% DEFINING COLORS COF, PUR, GREEO AND GREET
\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}
% OCTAHEDRON
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3]
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (0.6,0.2);
    \coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (A4) at (0.4,-0.2);
    \coordinate (B1) at (0.5,0.5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (0.5,-0.5);
    %
    \begin{scope}[thick,dashed,,opacity=0.6]
        \draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw (B1) -- (A2) -- (B2);
    \end{scope}
    %
    \draw[fill=cof,opacity=0.6] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[fill=pur,opacity=0.6] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    \draw[fill=greeo,opacity=0.6] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[fill=greet,opacity=0.6] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    \draw (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

% Bi-pyramid
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3]
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (A4) at (0.4,-0.2);
    \coordinate (B1) at (0.5,0.5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (0.5,-0.5);
    %
    \begin{scope}[thick,dashed,,opacity=0.6]
        \draw (A1)  -- (A3);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[fill=cof,opacity=0.6] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[fill=pur,opacity=0.6] (A1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    \draw[fill=greeo,opacity=0.6] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B1);
    \draw[fill=greet,opacity=0.6] (A3) -- (A4) -- (B2);
    %
    \draw (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You will get these two pictures:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Pst-solides3d](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d) already comes with some of the platonic bodies included. Examples and alternative approaches for polyhedra were presented [here on SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect). This may be easier than starting from scratch with [Sketch,](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/)[TeXCAD](http://texcad.sourceforge.net/), [Ipe](https://github.com/otfried/ipe-wiki/wiki/Showcase), or [LaTeXDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/).