# Tikzpicture at the same horizontal level in the page

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

How can I align two tikzpictures on the same line?
There are several suggestions but the trivial approach suggested in:

[How to draw two Tikz pictures that are parallel to each other?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24001/how-to-draw-two-tikz-pictures-that-are-parallel-to-each-other)

does not work for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis,axis equal]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,y domain=-2:2]
                ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis,axis equal]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,y domain=-2:2]
                ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which simply stacks the images:

[image: StackedImages]

Comment: The empty line between tikzpictures forces them to be on two different paragraphs. Insert `%` between them or just suppress empty line, and both will remain on same line.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213075/124842

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the empty line between the two `tikzpicture`s.  It separates the two images into separate paragraphs, hence the stacking.

Comment: Jeez Louize! Thx!